# question about reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

i have following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int i;
     char *p="this is a string";
     i=reinterpret_cast<int>(p);
     cout<<i<<"\n":



     return 0;
}
```

output is:
7648
please explain  reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast<>` here will convert without checking the `p` pointer to an `int` but you can't make any assumption what this `int` would represent. The only thing you can do, is convert this pointer back to what it was.

On a more practical note, it is likely that your compiler will put the address `p` points to into the `int` value, but `int` size may not match a system pointer size, so you should probably use something like `uintptr_t` for that instead of `int`.

You can use something like [Boost `lexical_cast<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) which would try to convert a string-representation of an integer to the real integer value but I'm not sure that was your goal here.

Comment: He is casting a char pointer to an int, not a char to an int. It's undefined anyway.

Comment: Except that this answer is still wrong. If we couldn't use `reinterpret_cast` in this case, what else could we use? Casting something unrelated like `char*` to `int` __is exactly what `reinterpret_cast` is for__. Of course, the result might, according to the standard, be anything and is highly platform-dependent. But when you need this, you `reinterpret_cast` is what the standard provides.

Comment: If you want to do this in a defined manner you should use a `uintptr_t` as the integer type. Then it should be perfectly fine to use `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 4):

`reinterpret_cast` causes the data that you are casting to be considered as a different type, without any conversion being performed. According to the standard, the only thing that is defined behavior after a `reinterpret_cast` is to `reinterpret_cast` it back to the original type.

This sounds a little useless, but one reason you might want to use this is, for example, using certain C libraries (e.g. pthreads) in C++. A lot of C libraries that involve callbacks pass a parameter of type `void*` to the callback. In C++, the proper way to deal with this is to take a pointer to whatever you want to use as the parameter, `reinterpret_cast` it to `void*` when passing it into the C library, and then `reinterpret_cast` it back to whatever it actually is inside the callback.

*While it is not guranteed to be defined behavior* by the standard, on most platforms/compilers, what a `reinterpret_cast` does is simply consider the data to be a different type, using the same bit pattern. For example, if you have a 32-bit double `d` whose bit pattern happens to be `01101010 00111100 01101010 01000001`, and you write `int i = reinterpret_cast<int>(d)`, then `i` will be an integer whose bit pattern `01101010 00111100 01101010 01000001`, even though that will represent a wildly different numeric value as an integer than it did as a double. And obviously, this can get you into trouble quickly if the types involved are not the same size.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).

What exactly is unclear? Please be specific. Also search before you ask, there are numerous questions about this on SO.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to explain. The result of `reinterpret_cast` is platform-specific. What you're test outputs is likely either the address of the string constant or whatever remains of it when it's coerced into an `int`.